# Exception during SaveAppointmentTask is showing

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I try to open a SaveAppointmentTask in code like this:

```
var saveAppointmentTask = new SaveAppointmentTask();

saveAppointmentTask.StartTime = e.Epg.StartDateTime;
saveAppointmentTask.EndTime = e.Epg.EndDateTime;
saveAppointmentTask.Subject = "some subject";
saveAppointmentTask.Location = "some location";
saveAppointmentTask.Details = "details";
saveAppointmentTask.IsAllDayEvent = false;
saveAppointmentTask.Reminder = Reminder.FifteenMinutes;
saveAppointmentTask.AppointmentStatus = Microsoft.Phone.UserData.AppointmentStatus.Free;

saveAppointmentTask.Show();
```

but when calendar was opened exception going occured:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: State saving failed. This is most likely due
>   to insufficient State buffer capacity. App requires [3562259] bytes
>   which likely exceeds NavServer limit

In my app I'm using caliburn.micro.

Is any one know what really happend and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try replacing `SaveAppointmentTask` and use `EmailComposeTask` instead, just to see if the same exception occurs.

Comment: yeap. Same situation, the same exception. Seems to be a problem with Pause of app. It takes too long or something.

Comment: Just as I have suspected. I am not familiar with Caliburn.Micro, but I suspect that you have a large view model that gets serialized on application deactivation.

Comment: Maybe.. but it's not happens when I click middle button which start the same pause action. I will try to debug with more control of saving my vms and services.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `IEventAggregator` instead of creating an SaveAppointmentTask by yourself

```
_eventAggregator.RequestTask<SaveAppointmentTask>(saveAppointmentTask =>
                                                          {
                                                              saveAppointmentTask.StartTime = e.Epg.StartDateTime;
                                                              saveAppointmentTask.EndTime = e.Epg.EndDateTime;
                                                              saveAppointmentTask.Subject = "some subject";
                                                              saveAppointmentTask.Location = "some location";
                                                              saveAppointmentTask.Details = "details";
                                                              saveAppointmentTask.IsAllDayEvent = false;
                                                              saveAppointmentTask.Reminder = Reminder.FifteenMinutes;
                                                              saveAppointmentTask.AppointmentStatus = Microsoft.Phone.UserData.AppointmentStatus.Free;

                                                          });
```